# jquery tabs method is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have couple of simple tabs, I am trying to apply activate flag on first tag when page loads, then i will have my own condition to load second.i am having a problem when i call `tabs()` or `tabs({activate : 0})`. it initially loading as expected but after a moment it throws a big exception starting like

`jquery.js:7840 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {`

Brings an environment as close to ECMAScript 5 compliance
  as is possible with the facilities of erstwhile engines.

really appreciate if some one can help me here.

```
   <div class="tabs" id="orderHistoryTabs">
   <ul class="tabsList">
    <c:forEach items="${component.tabList}" var="tab" varStatus="status">
        <li class="tab-${status.index}"><a href="${tab.url}" 
       onclick="loading();">${tab.linkName}</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#orderHistoryTabs").tabs();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: can you please post a plunker ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/n15JtBJHJJOJ9RSpb95q?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FVzVaJ7yASiZK7UCXuHN?p=preview

Comment: I dont see any issues as long as you import your jquery and jquery ui. Please refer above plnkr

Answer (score 0):

I think the error say that you need to put in a anonymous function.

```
 $(function () {
      $("#orderHistoryTabs").tabs();
    });
```